# JavaScript IF statement with conditions from input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a simple calc usign values from input fileds, but I have a problem with passing values to if statement. It looks like this:

```
$('#confirmSila').click(function(){
var dlugosc = $('#sila').val();
var silaOd = $('.silaOd').val();
var silaDo = $('.silaDo').val();
if ((dlugosc > silaOd) && (dlugosc < silaDo))
{
//$('#orderWymiar').attr('value', dlugosc);
$('#sila').css('border', '1px solid green');
$('.silaInfo').text('Statement true');
}else{
$('#wymiar').css('border', '1px solid red');
$('.silaInfo').text('silaOd must be more than' + silaOd + ', and less than ' + silaDo);
}
});
```

And, the wird thing is that, when force is 20, JavaScript says that it passed the statemenst, when in input `.silaOd` is typed 100.   (silaOd meand minForce, and sildaDo means maxForce in Poland)

I dont have any idea, why that is happening.  Please help! :)

There's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/rJA6U/

Comment: I hope those variables are understandable in a language you speak, because if not that's just confusing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run `parseInt()` on the input values, like so:

```
var dlugosc = parseInt($('#sila').val());
var silaOd = parseInt($('.silaOd').val());
var silaDo = parseInt($('.silaDo').val());
```

Comment: you might consider this as well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240490/jquery-parseint-not-playing-nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing strings so < or > does not work.  You need to cast them as int.

example:

```
parseInt(dlugosc) > parseInt(sila0d)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$.fn.tryParseInt = function(defaultValue) {

    var 
        retValue = defaultValue,
        actualValue = $(this).val();

    if (actualValue != null) {
        if (actualValue.length > 0) {
            if (!isNaN(actualValue)) {
                retValue = parseInt(actualValue);
            }
        }
    }

    return retValue;
}


var 
  dlugosc = $('#sila').tryParseInt(0),
  silaOd = $('.silaOd').tryParseInt(0),
  silaDo = $('.silaDo').tryParseInt(0);
```

based on [this link](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/01/14/JavaScript-intTryParse-Equivalent.aspx)